# App not showing on drop down menu when trying to upload

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode5

I've built and archived an app as usual on XCode 5.1.1. When trying to Distribute it using the XCode Organiser, the app doesn't show up on the drop down menu under 'Choose an application record and a profile to sign up with:'. The provisioning profile shows up correctly, but the app isn't on the list above.

I've tried the following:

- Restart XCode
- Restart computer (I left it off overnight and then restarted again in the morning)
- Clean, build and archive again
- Wait a couple of hours, then a couple of days in case the problem was server based
- Renew provisioning profiles, rearchive

The app does exist on iTunes Connect and I've double checked I'm trying to log in using the correct account credentials. I built 3 apps over the course of yesterday, the first and third of which don't show up, but the second was submitted with no issues.

This is getting really frustrating - any help is welcome! Thanks

Edit: The 2nd app which was submitted with no issues and is in 'Waiting for review' status no longer appears on drop down menu either.

Edit 2: The 3rd app has now appeared on the drop down and has been submitted correctly. The 1st and 2nd still don't show up though.

Edit 3: None of the 3 show up on the drop down menu - every other app on the account shows up fine.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45IEO.jpg

Comment: Have you archived the apps that are in question? Within Xcode open the project and in the tool bar click Product>Archive. Also, the active scheme must be set to a real device and not a simulator for it to archive properly. Which drop down menu are you talking about specifically? Would you be able to upload a screen shot?

Comment: I've archived the apps multiple times as usual (clean, build, archive with an actual device on XCode) - I've submitted over 500 apps before this with no issue. The drop down in question is shown on the screenshot (link at end of OP) - the Audi Tuner app doesn't show up on the Application drop down at the top.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me twice.

It was "fixed" both times after I made a trivial change to the app Description on iTunes Connect and saved the change. Perhaps that somehow caused iTunes Connect or Xcode to update a cache somewhere.

Specifically I:

- Logged into iTunes Connect in a web browser
- Clicked My Apps
- Clicked the large icon for the app in question
- On the Versions tab
- In the Description field (below "app video preview" and "Name)
- - pasted some new text
- Clicked Save (in the upper-right above "Version Information")

Then my app started appearing in the Application drop-down on the "Choose an application record and a profile to sign up with" dialog.

I assume that changing any other field and saving would have the same effect, but I haven't tested it.